# How do I use sudo with python inside virtualenvironment

Tags: python, virtualenv, sudo, virtual-environment

Hi I am trying to run a python script as sudo from inside my virtualenvironment.

When I have activated my virtualenvironment I would normally use `python somescript.py` and my script starts up with the correct version of python and everything

When I use `sudo python somescript.py` I load up the wrong python install, which is not the one from my environment.

How do I resove this?

Comment: You need to install the correct version of python in your virtual env. Are you using Conda for your enviroments or something else?

Comment: I am using venv
I created the environment with this command  python3 -m venv ‘Name‘

Comment: Why does your Python script need sudo privileges?

Comment: Very often, activating the virtual environment is not necessary. Have you tried something like `sudo path/to/venv/bin/python somescript.py`?

Answer (score 6):

The *activate* script sets some environment variables (defines some functions, ...), which facilitate invoking *Python* (and tools). 
One way (more like a workaround) of achieving your goal, would be the variables to be carried across the [[man7]: sudo(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sudo.8.html) session. For that, you need to:

- Pass the ***-E*** flag to *sudo*
- *PATH* needs to be carried manually ([[StackExchange.Unix]: How to make `sudo` preserve $PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path))

All in all:

```bash
sudo -E env PATH=${PATH} python somescript.py
```

**Output** (works for simple commands):

> ```bash
> (py_venv_pc064_03.05.02_test0) [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q061715573]> python3 -c "import sys, os; print(\"EXE: {0:s}\nPATH: {1:s}\n\".format(sys.executable, os.environ[\"PATH\"]))"
> EXE: /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_venv_pc064_03.05.02_test0/bin/python3
> PATH: /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_venv_pc064_03.05.02_test0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
>
> (py_venv_pc064_03.05.02_test0) [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q061715573]> sudo python3 -c "import sys, os; print(\"EXE: {0:s}\nPATH: {1:s}\n\".format(sys.executable, os.environ[\"PATH\"]))"
> EXE: /usr/bin/python3
> PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
>
> (py_venv_pc064_03.05.02_test0) [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q061715573]> sudo -E env PATH=${PATH} python3 -c "import sys, os; print(\"EXE: {0:s}\nPATH: {1:s}\n\".format(sys.executable, os.environ[\"PATH\"]))"
> EXE: /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_venv_pc064_03.05.02_test0/bin/python3
> PATH: /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_venv_pc064_03.05.02_test0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
> ```

The one way that never fails in this kind of situations, is using (*Python*'s) executable full path. But since that's just a *symlink*, you'd probably want to preserve the environment anyway:

```bash
sudo -E env PATH=${PATH} /somePath/someFolder/myEnvironment/bin/python somescript.py
```

Comment: this still loads up the python from `/user/bin/python`, not the one thats in the virtual environment

Comment: You;re probably not in the *venv* when you launch *sudo*.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is answered in here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/234758/how-to-use-a-python-virtualenv-with-sudo

> The issue is almost certainly that when you run sudo, the virtualenv
>   environment variables, aliases, functions, etc aren't being carried
>   over.
>
> The solution would be to explicitly run the virtual environment's
>   Python executable with sudo. For example if your virtualenv is
>   ./AwesomeProject, then you could run sudo ./AwesomeProject/bin/python
>    to use the script with the virtualenv with root privileges.

Comment: when I try doing this, it does not load the correct python it seems. Basically I am doing this whole thing to work with tensorflow, specifically the newest nightly build of that.
When I open python with `sudo ./name_of_venv/bin/python` and check the installed version, it is not the tensorflow build that I wanna use

Comment: what is `which python` telling when you are running correct one?

Comment: which python is showing me the path to the virtual environment
/somePath/someFolder/myEnvironment/bin/python
while sudo which python is giving me 
/user/bin/python

Comment: So you should be use `sudo  /somePath/someFolder/myEnvironment/bin/python` to use correct that as sudo. Or maybe you have installed Tensorflow into other location you intended?

Comment: when I try to just load up that python with `sudo /somePath/someFolder/myEnvironment/bin/python` I get unable to execute permission denied